# How to access var in PHP

Tags: php, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium-rc with php. I want to show in my test the value of CLASSNAME. How can i present the var? I tried to do `$this['drivers']['CLASSNAME']` but this is not working for me.

[image]

(This is from the debug)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it should be:

`$this->drivers[0]->CLASSNAME`